# When deploying a new feature config files are not loaded before bundles are started

Tags: jbossfuse, fabric8

I'm evaluating jboss fuse (using version 6.2.1.redhat-084), and i've run into the following issue:

- I have a number of features in my project
- Each feature has a configuration file
- The feature repository file looks like this:

.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<features name="myservice-features" xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.2.0">
    <feature name="myservice-common" version="${project.version}">
        <configfile finalname="etc/com.myorg.myservice_common.cfg" override="true">mvn:com.myorg/myservice-common/${project.version}/cfg/${build.environment}</configfile>
        <bundle start-level="100" dependency="true">mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.javax-cache-api/1.0.0_1</bundle>
        <bundle start-level="100" dependency="true">mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-velocity/${camel.version}</bundle>
        <bundle start-level="110">mvn:com.myorg/myservice-common/${project.version}</bundle>
    </feature>
    <feature name="myservice-impl" version="${project.version}">
        <feature>myservice-common</feature>
        <configfile finalname="etc/com.myorg.myservice.cfg" override="true">mvn:com.myorg/myservice-impl/${project.version}/cfg/${build.environment}</configfile>
        <bundle start-level="200">mvn:com.hazelcast/hazelcast/${hazelcast.version}</bundle>
        <bundle start-level="200">mvn:com.hazelcast/hazelcast-client/${hazelcast.version}</bundle>
        <bundle start-level="220">mvn:com.myorg/myservice-impl/${project.version}</bundle>
    </feature>
</features>
```

- The service uses blueprint property placeholder with the corresponding PID to initialize the properties in the camel context
- The issue is that when deploying the features in a profile, the configuration files are picked up by org.apache.felix.fileinstall only after the bundles are attempted to be resolved, and I run into the following exception:

.

```
    2016-12-15 10:07:38,384 | ERROR | oyer-49-thread-1 | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 23 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.4.4 | Unable to start blueprint container for bundle otc-trade-service-impl/1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Unable to initialize bean .camelBlueprint.factory.myservice-impl-context
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.runBeanProcInit(BeanRecipe.java:714)[23:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property placeholder key: xxxxx not found
        at org.apache.camel.blueprint.BlueprintPropertiesParser.parseProperty(BlueprintPropertiesParser.java:164)
        at org.apache.camel.component.properties.DefaultPropertiesParser$ParsingContext.doGetPropertyValue(DefaultPropertiesParser.java:306)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
        at org.apache.camel.component.properties.DefaultPropertiesParser$ParsingContext.getPropertyValue(DefaultPropertiesParser.java:246)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
        at org.apache.camel.component.properties.DefaultPropertiesParser$ParsingContext.readProperty(DefaultPropertiesParser.java:154)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
        at org.apache.camel.component.properties.DefaultPropertiesParser$ParsingContext.doParse(DefaultPropertiesParser.java:113)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
        at org.apache.camel.component.properties.DefaultPropertiesParser$ParsingContext.parse(DefaultPropertiesParser.java:97)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
        at org.apache.camel.component.properties.DefaultPropertiesParser.parseUri(DefaultPropertiesParser.java:62)
        at org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent.parseUri(PropertiesComponent.java:178)
        at org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent.parseUri(PropertiesComponent.java:129)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.resolvePropertyPlaceholders(DefaultCamelContext.java:1956)
        at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinitionHelper.resolvePropertyPlaceholders(ProcessorDefinitionHelper.java:734)
        at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinitionHelper.initRouteInputs(RouteDefinitionHelper.java:379)
        ... 47 more
```

- This looks similar to issue https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ENTESB-593; however, looks like the 'fix' to that issue involved only having the configuration files copied into the ${karaf.base}/etc folder, but not actually triggering and synchronizing on karaf configuration manager before starting the bundles

I'm a bit stuck with this issue. Obviously I could just set 'start="false"' for my bundles and manually start all the camel context bundles after profile deployment, but I'd like to know if there is a more optimal solution.

Comment: Did you try using JBoss Fuse 6.3.0?

Answer (score 0):

I've come up up with the following hacky workaround so far:

- Add a dependency for org.osgi:org.osgi.compendium:5.0.0 and org.osgi:org.osgi.core:5.0.0
- Create the following BundleActivator class:

.

```
package com.myorg.common;

import org.osgi.framework.Bundle;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.framework.ServiceRegistration;
import org.osgi.service.cm.Configuration;
import org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationEvent;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.Dictionary;

public class ConfigurationActivator implements BundleActivator {

    public static final String BUNDLE_CONFIGURATION_WATCH = "bundle.configuration.watch";
    public static final String BUNDLE_SYMBOLIC_NAME = "bundle.symbolic.name";

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConfigurationActivator.class);
    private ServiceRegistration<org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationListener> listenerReg;

    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        LOG.debug("Bundle " + context.getBundle().getSymbolicName() + " starting");
        listenerReg = context.registerService(org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationListener.class,
                new ConfigurationListener(context), null);
    }

    public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        LOG.debug("Bundle " + context.getBundle().getSymbolicName() + " stopping");
        if (listenerReg != null) {
            listenerReg.unregister();
        }
    }

    public class ConfigurationListener implements org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationListener {
        private BundleContext bundleContext;

        public ConfigurationListener(BundleContext bundleContext) {
            this.bundleContext = bundleContext;
        }

        public void configurationEvent(ConfigurationEvent configurationEvent) {
            try {
                if (configurationEvent.getType() == ConfigurationEvent.CM_UPDATED) {
                    LOG.debug("Configuration update event: " + configurationEvent.getPid());
                    Bundle bundle = bundleContext.getBundle();
                    LOG.trace("Bundle " + bundle.getSymbolicName() + " state: " + bundle.getState());
                    try {
                        Configuration configuration = bundleContext.getService(configurationEvent.getReference()).getConfiguration(configurationEvent.getPid());
                        if (configuration != null) {
                            Dictionary<String, Object> properties = configuration.getProperties();
                            if (properties != null) {
                                if (Boolean.TRUE.toString().equals(properties.get(BUNDLE_CONFIGURATION_WATCH))
                                        && bundle.getSymbolicName().equals(properties.get(BUNDLE_SYMBOLIC_NAME))) {
                                    LOG.info("Updating bundle " + bundle.getSymbolicName() + " due to configuration change");
                                    bundle.update();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            } catch (IllegalStateException se) {
                LOG.warn("Bundle context has been invalidated");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Add this bundle activator to the bundle manifest
- Add the following properties to your configuration file:

  ```
  bundle.configuration.watch=true
  bundle.symbolic.name=<bundle-name>
  ```
- Deploy the feature. If the configuration has changed after the bundle has already attempted to start, the bundle will be updated

This still feels inelegant to me due to two reasons:

1. Additional configuration properties
2. The original issue will still cause confusing error messages in the logs during deployment

Can anyone suggest a better answer?